# Sql Injection issue on select query Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, sql-injection

Here is my sql for which I am getting sql injection issue. I need to make this sql in rails way

Here is rails way select query :

```
select_string = "travel_items.*, 6371.0 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((#{lat} - travel_items.lat) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2) + COS(#{lat} * PI() / 180) * COS(travel_items.lat * PI() / 180) * POWER(SIN((#{lng} - travel_items.lng) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2))) AS distance, MOD(CAST((ATAN2( ((travel_items.lng - #{lng}) / 57.2957795), ((travel_items.lat - #{lat}) / 57.2957795)) * 57.2957795) + 360 AS decimal), 360) AS bearing"
where_string = ["travel_items.lat BETWEEN ?  AND ? AND travel_items.lng BETWEEN ?  AND ?  AND (6371.0 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN(( ? - travel_items.lat) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2) + COS( ? * PI() / 180) * COS(travel_items.lat * PI() / 180) * POWER(SIN((? - travel_items.lng) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2)))) BETWEEN 0.0 AND ?",min_lat,max_lat, min_lng, max_lng, mid_lat, mid_lat, mid_lng, distance_km]
TravelItem.select(select_string).where("travel_items.type = ?", travel_item_type).where(where_string).order('distance').limit(limit).to_a
```

For `where_string` I am not getting sql injection issue. I am getting it only on `select_string` . Can we have solution to remove sql injection on this?

Answer (score 0):

Ref [this](http://www.alexehrnschwender.com/2013/10/dynamic-activerecord-querying-rails-4/).
Try following

```
where_string = "travel_items.lat BETWEEN ?  AND ?" 
where_string += " AND travel_items.lng BETWEEN ?  AND ?"
where_string += " AND (6371.0 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN(( ? - travel_items.lat) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2) + COS( ? * PI() / 180) * COS(travel_items.lat * PI() / 180) * POWER(SIN((? - travel_items.lng) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2)))) BETWEEN 0.0 AND ?"

where_array = [min_lat,max_lat, min_lng, max_lng, mid_lat, 
               mid_lat, mid_lng, distance_km]
where_array.insert(0, where_string)


TravelItem.select(select_string).where("travel_items.type = ?", travel_item_type).where(where_array).order('distance').limit(limit).to_a
```

Comment: Hi Salil. Thank for the reply. But I mentioned in question that `where_string` is not giving me sql injection issue. Its the `select_string`